# Kubuntu 16.04 LTS - External monitor is not detected anymore

Tags: kubuntu, lenovo, thinkpad, xrandr

I have a weird problem. On firday i disconnected my Lenovo ThinkPad Yoga 460 from my external monitor and today i reconnected it and it seems that the monitor is not detected anymore. The monitor as well as the hdmi cable seems to be ok, because they work with other laptops.

the output of `sudo lshw -C display`

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:277 memory:d0000000-d0ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

The output of `xrandr`

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
   1920x1080     59.98*+  59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     59.98  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     59.98
```

I will provide further information if needed!

Comment: Do you connect the monitor when the laptop is off or on?   Are you able to give the command:  xrandr --output HDMI-1 --auto

Comment: I don't know what it was, but it did the trick. thank you

Comment: It seems that my laptop wasn't shutdown correctly...lol